# I2C between two arduinos

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, i2c

I have 4 gyro sensors that communicate to arduino uno using I2C and then arduino uno sends the data to arduino mega.
I was wondering if I could use i2c for this purpose or if I should look for other methods.
gyro sensor used in the project:
https://www.pololu.com/product/2129/resources

Comment: Sure, the Mega can be an I2C slave, too. Is there a reason, why you are using a Mega and an Uno, instead of just the Mega?

Comment: ok so the arduino uno can be both a slave and a master. thanks
yes, I will be adding a bunch of analog sensors to the project later and I don't have enough unused I/O pins on the Mega to connect them to, so I'm using 2 boards.

Comment: Both master and slave is not adviserable. The I2C protocol has multi master support,  but the `Wire` library does not implement this. If the gyro sensors use I2C and you already considered to use I2C between the Uno and Mega, why don't you connect the gyro sensors to the Mega? They will only use the 2 I2C pins, that you already planned in, since they are all I2C sensors.

Comment: thats better thank you!